# tcpdump file size = network traffic?

Tags: tcpdump

I measured my network traffic on mulitple nodes at the same time via tcpdump. I would like calculate my network traffic without importing every single file into wireshark. Am I correct that each file includes tx+rx traffic? Does the following formula roughly describe the overall network traffic?

```
(tcpdump_file_size_host_1 + tcpdump_file_size_host_2 + ... + tcpdump_file_size_host_n) / 2
```

So all file sizes aggregated divided by 2 because of rx+tx traffic. Does anyone know the overhead of the file to be a bit more precise?

Comment: Alright. I did a little test with a 6,4 MB tcdump file. The overall traffic (rx +tx) was 12,52 MB. 12,52 MB / 2 = 6,26 MB network traffic.

Comment: The answer to your question would depend on the configuration of the NIC/Switch/Tap where you are sniffing and the filter (if any) that you are using with tcpdump.

Comment: I'm new to this and used the default config: `tcpdump -i eth0 -w "dump_file"`

Comment: There is no guarantee that each host is capturing the same traffic or that the captures were started and stopped at the exact same time, thus some traffic is almost certainly going to be present in one capture file but not another.  I think you're better off capturing at a single point using a TAP or Span port rather than trying to aggregate the data from multiple capture files.  For a good tutorial/write-up on capturing, I might refer you to Jasper's 6-part "Network Capture Playbook" series beginning with https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/10/the-network-capture-playbook-part-1-ethernet-basics/

Comment: I'm trying to analyze the network traffic for some Impala queries (multiple gb of data) within my own docker overlay network. This is the only thing running there. Therefore, I wrote a script that starts and stops tcpdump and the same time (or with a very small script delay) when the query starts/ends. You're totally right that my analysis is very rough but as there a multiple gb transferred and only of few bytes of communication I wanted to go this way.